# Can not read Response.Body from server in .Net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, api-gateway, asp.net-core-middleware

I track request/response log in middleware of Api gateway .Net5, I can able to read Request.Body, However, I do not understand the body of the response, it show like below

```
 `�      <�_O�0G��r_����%>�"A�8��[��Im���
�w7n��{rO��/�կZ~y����36������rNIJ��d�w��\�'�����|w-�!�OR#Q�fi�X��   G��Sg�`��X@��{��KE�k�T3Zj%5N�@���+��SY��[�׊C(w� �·��@"�E���UnM�}��Jc�k�����F����#��$q�O(�.tÃ�c�ӕW����  �� ID�P`
```

Here I share my read response code

```
              string responseBody = string.Empty;
                var originalBodyStream = context?.Response.Body;

                //Create a new memory stream...
                using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                        context.Response.Body = responseStream;
                        await _next.Invoke(context);
                        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        responseBody = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();
                        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
                }
```

And this is my request header

```
{
    "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip",
    "Accept-Language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
    "Content-Length":"2",
    "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
   }
```

Comment: This is obviously a binary file (a GZIP file), not text. `StreamReader` is only meant for text input.

Comment: "Content-Length":"2", must be wrong.

Comment: @PoulBak It created by browser

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot, Now i can read using SharpZipLib package

Comment: You don't have to. ASP.NET Core already supports compression and decompression. It already supports request and response logging. Your own middleware seems to be running too late, after the response was already compressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can read using SharpZipLib package,
This code working for me

```
            GZipInputStream unGzipStream = new GZipInputStream(response.Body);
            var responseBodytxt = new StreamReader(unGzipStream).ReadToEnd();
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: *While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.*

Comment: That's not a good solution. ASP.NET Core already supports compression and [request/response logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It supports other compression algorithms too, which won't work with SharpZipLib. All you really need to do is use `services.AddHttpLogging`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to write your own response logging code. ASP.NET Core already supports [HTTP Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It supports response compression using multiple algorithms too, including Brotli, which isn't supported by SharpZipLib.

[To enable logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#enabling-http-logging) all that's needed is a call to `app.UseHttpLogging()`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpLogging();
...
```

Requests and responses will be logged as `Information` messages from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware` source. The destination of those messages can be configured using Logging configuration, through code or configuration settings.

ASP.NET Core doesn't have a built-in file provider. One of the most common options is to use [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore), which can be configured to log messages from different sources to different files:

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
...
```

and in `CreateHostBuilder()` :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog() // <-- Add this line
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

The ASP.NET Core Serilog integration also includes [Request logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#request-logging).

Logging to different files by eg log level is possible by passing a parameter to `File`, eg:

```
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File("log.txt",LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.File("errors.txt",LogEventLevel.Error)
```

Logging to different sinks can be configured using [sub-loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#sub-loggers):

```
.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware>())
    .WriteTo.File("http.txt"))
```